# How to install Linux ubuntu and not lose data on other partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, installation

I have five partitions: C, D, E, F, and G, each of which has 195GB. I want to switch from Windows to Linux completely. My D partition contains all my important files, like recorded classes.

Can I keep my D partition without losing any data?

Even if I installed Ubuntu without deleting partition D, can I still access it through Linux normally?

Answer (score 0):

If you had only one drive and this would be a NFTS formatted drive, linux would have to reformat and you'd lose all the files on this partition.

Best practice would be to create a partition (in your case you could use E:). Move the contents you want to keep to the new partition. Install ubuntu on drive d without wiping windows. Load ubuntu and copy files from your E drive to D drive. Then you can format C drive and get rid of windows.

As another best practice, I'd advise to make a backup anyway in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I keep my D partition without losing any data?

YES.

But if the data is important **you should have backups**. Mistakes happen all the time even to advanced users. And mistakes are due to happen when using manual partitioning which is a must in this case given the proposed scenario. Especially in this situation where you're asking a utterly trivial question that any beginner knows the answer to. As always, if you're asking this question, you don't know enough yet so **you MUST have backups**.

> Even if I installed Ubuntu without deleting partition D, can I still access it through Linux normally?

YES, typically...

But if said partition has been used by any Windows 8 or newer with the default Fast Startup settings then **you should disable Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown properly before deleting/overwriting Windows**.

In any case, **do your backups** to a different drive. Although Ubuntu can r/w to NTFS out-of-the-box since almost the beginning of the distro, if not dual-booting with Windows (i.e., standalone Ubuntu), **NTFS partitions shouldn't be kept around, Linux has NO tools to error correct said file system**, you always need Windows and Windows tools to correct errors in NTFS partitions and it's not a matter of *if*, it's *when*.

In a nutshell, **the only way to "not loose data" is to have it backed up**.